# How can I get the values from Map<String List<Object>>

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

I have a model class `EmployeeBaseData.java` which looks like this (This is just for example):

```
public class EmployeeBaseData {
public EmployeeBaseData(String sid){
    this.sid = sid;

}
private String sid;
private int actualHours = 10;
private int regularHours = 9;
private int overtime = 1;
public String getSid() {
    return sid;
}
public void setSid(String sid) {
    this.sid = sid;
}
public int getActualHours() {
    return actualHours;
}
public void setActualHours(int actualHours) {
    this.actualHours = actualHours;
}
public int getRegularHours() {
    return regularHours;
}
public void setRegularHours(int regularHours) {
    this.regularHours = regularHours;
}
public int getOvertime() {
    return overtime;
}
public void setOvertime(int overtime) {
    this.overtime = overtime;
}
```

This is the controller:

```
public class InputController {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Map<String, List<Object>> employeeMap = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
        EmployeeBaseData base_data1 = new EmployeeBaseData("e774801");
        EmployeeBaseData base_data2 = new EmployeeBaseData("e774802");
        List<Object> valSetOne = new ArrayList<Object>();
        List<Object> valSetTwo = new ArrayList<Object>();
        valSetOne.add(base_data1);
        valSetTwo.add(base_data2);
        employeeMap.put("e774801", valSetOne);
        employeeMap.put("e774802", valSetTwo);
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : employeeMap.entrySet()){
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<Object> value= entry.getValue();

        }
```

Now the question is if I need to access the `getOverTime()` method of the model, then how can I get it from the map?

Comment: Why you don't use generic like :  Map<String, List<EmployeeBaseData >> employeeMap

Answer (score 1):

@epoch has the right idea with regard to the proper definition of the map. It's worth pointing out, however, that Java 8 gives you a very elegant way of getting all the overtimes, without having to write cumbersome loops:

```
List<Integer> overtimes = 
    employeeMap.values()
               .stream()
               .flatMap(Collection::stream)
               .map(EmployeeBaseData::getOvertime)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer of epoch. (i.e. using a `List<EmployeeBaseData>`)

Alternatively, if you also want to store other types of objects in your list, then a `List<Object>` is ok. In that case you can just **check the type** and **perform a cast**:

```
   for(Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : employeeMap.entrySet()){
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<Object> valueList = entry.getValue();
        for (Object item : valueList)
        {
          // CHECK THE TYPE
          if (item instanceof EmployeeBaseData)
          {
             // PERFORM A CAST
             EmployeeBaseData ebd = (EmployeeBaseData) item;
             int overtime = ebd.getOverTime();
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using an `Object` as the generic type for your `ArrayList`, you should specify the data type within the `List`, i.e:

```
    Map<String, List<EmployeeBaseData >> employeeMap = new HashMap<String, List<EmployeeBaseData >>();

    EmployeeBaseData base_data1 = new EmployeeBaseData("e774801");
    EmployeeBaseData base_data2 = new EmployeeBaseData("e774802");

    List<EmployeeBaseData > valSetOne = new ArrayList<>();
    List<EmployeeBaseData > valSetTwo = new ArrayList<>();

    valSetOne.add(base_data1);
    valSetTwo.add(base_data2);

    employeeMap.put("e774801", valSetOne);
    employeeMap.put("e774802", valSetTwo);

    for(Map.Entry<String, List<EmployeeBaseData>> entry : employeeMap.entrySet()){
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<EmployeeBaseData> value = entry.getValue();

        // access objects here:
        for (EmployeeBaseData a : value) {
            a.getOverTime();
        }
    }
```